# Convert scanned pdf in black/white

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, pdftk

I have a question about converting the colour of pdf-files, i don't find the solution:

Due to the growing spread of multi-function-printers everybody is able to scan-to-pdf, but many people do not understand the functions of the scanner. As a result, I'm receiving more and more emails from clients with a 10MB-high-resolution-24bit-colour-scan-attachment, that just contains b/w-text.

Is it possible to convert these scans in windows with ghostscript or pdftk to b/w? I've searched the web and tried something with both tools, some results were even b/w but as big as the input-file.

Background for the question is that I need to archive those attachments, but don't want to waste capacity and power of the dms-database for unneeded colours.

Thank you for all answers and sorry for the bad english ;-)

Comment: You just need to use a conversion that will convert the pdf to a 1 bpp pdf with a good compression, such as ccittg4 or lzw.